# passing a struct to a IDispatch method

Tags: windows, visual-c++, com, atl, idispatch

In a third party COM Module I have to pass a struct to a Method.

The important parts of the IDL definition look like this:

```
interface ITheirInterface : IDispatch {
    [id(0x0000012d)]
    HRESULT TheirMethod([in] TheirStruct Attributes);
};

struct TheirStruct {
    BSTR TheirFieldA;
    BSTR TheirFieldB;
} TheirStruct;
```

I how do I call the method from C++ using the ATL?

```
CComPtr<IDispatch> comPtr; 
comPtr.CoCreateInstance(L"theirModule.TheirCoClass");
CComVariant returnValue;
CComVariant attribute= I_DO_NOT_KNOW_WHAT_TO_PLACE_HERE;
comPtr.Invoke1(T2COLE(L"TheirMethod"),&attribute,&returnValue);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COM automation support for structures is very weak, CComVariant doesn't support it directly.  You need to use IRecordInfo and create a variant of type VT_RECORD.  Obtain the IRecordInfo interface pointer from GetRecordInfoFromTypeInfo or GetRecordInfoFromGuids.  Good luck.

Comment: Googling a bit, I found a german article in the MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb979533.aspx I think, the last listing does what you where explaining. Am I right?

Comment: Yup, note the call to GetRecordInfoFromGuids.